# Синтаксис JS с двоеточием и знаком вопроса. Не тернарный оператор

Tags: javascript

Стыдно признаватсья, но я не знаю, что это за синтаксис такой. Наткнулся на исходниках [Vue Router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/util/route.js)

Интересны вот такое строки:

```
export function createRoute (
  record: ?RouteRecord,
  location: Location,
  redirectedFrom?: ?Location,
  router?: VueRouter
): Route {...
```

Тут встречаются двоеточия и знаки вопроса в определениях переменных.
А здесь

```
function formatMatch (record: ?RouteRecord): Array<RouteRecord> {...
```

после определения функции тоже интересный синтаксис. Да и в самой сигнатуре опять вопросы и двоеточия. Я бы сказал, что это тайпскрипт, но файлик-то .js. Просветите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это и есть TypeScript. А файл может быть хоть .js, хоть .jpg

Comment: @EssleJaxcate спасибо. Я был уверен, что надо .ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это Flow. Тоже похож на TypeScript. В [настройках rollup](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/build/configs.js) можно заметить, что подключается flow